# Selecionar resto de união entre tabelas

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho duas tabelas, CLIENTES e VENDAS.
Gostaria de saber quais clientes não tem nenhuma venda, sendo que armazeno na tabela vendas o ID do cliente.

Tentei isso mas sem sucesso:

```
SELECT *
FROM cliente
RIGHT JOIN vendas ON (vendas.id_cliente = cliente.id)
WHERE vendas.id_cliente IS NULL
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a cláusula *NOT EXISTS*

```
SELECT * FROM cliente
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT vendas.id_cliente FROM vendas WHERE vendas.id_cliente = cliente.id)
```

Se a *subquery* não retornar registos é porque não existe esse id de cliente na tabela *vendas*, isso faz que *EXISTS* seja falso, o *NOT* torna-o verdadeiro e esse cliente é retornado pelo *SELECT*.

Comment: Exato, o melhor caminho, assim acaso ele use um sistema de paginação ele não terá dificuldade em usar o `LIMIT offset, ...`

Answer (score 0):

Tenta com o `LEFT JOIN`, assim:

```
SELECT *
FROM cliente
LEFT JOIN vendas ON (vendas.id_cliente = cliente.id)
WHERE vendas.id_cliente IS NULL
```

Comment: Left join ele traz os dados tbm. Mais não é obrigatorio.
Se ele tiver alguma venda traz do mesmo jeito.

Comment: Concordo com você que o LEFT JOIN vai trazer tudo, mas por isso usamos "WHERE vendas.id_cliente IS NULL" vai filtrar só quem não tem venda. -1 por isso?

Comment: Pela lógica não temos vendas sem clientes, e podemos ter clientes sem vendas. vo retirar o -1

Answer (score 0):

**Olá, Tente isto**:

```
SELECT *
FROM cliente
RIGHT JOIN vendas ON (vendas.id_cliente = cliente.id)
WHERE vendas.id_cliente = NULL
```

Comment: Podes explicar porque esta solução pode resolver o problema. Assim o AP (autor da pergunta) vai perceber o que estava errado e como resolver o problema...